# Linux: Undefined reference to "sleep", even though I included unistd.h

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

Trying to use `sleep()` to pause my program briefly.
Except when I "make" I get an `undefined reference to sleep`, even though I `#include <unistd.h>` at the top.

> ```
> In function `main':
> [...]/source/ball.c:232: undefined reference to `sleep' 
> [...]/source/ball.c:240: undefined reference to `sleep'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

I'm using linux.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

EDIT: This Is not a duplicate question because every other time this question has been asked, the user was running it on Windows. The solution. for me, is not simply to include the windows header.

EDIT(2): The link to that other question does not help me. That's why I made a new post. I'm not on windows!!

Comment: What do you mean by "when i make"? can you paste the exact error you are getting and the exact command that triggers it?

Comment: When I run the make command to compile my project....

Comment: Here's the error: 
In function `main':
/home/bobo_baggins/Documents/212/project/ball-demo/source/ball.c:232: undefined reference to `sleep'
/home/bobo_baggins/Documents/212/project/ball-demo/source/ball.c:240: undefined reference to `sleep'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, and the compiler's messages *in the question*.

Comment: Does a much simpler program that uses `sleep` link successfully?

Comment: Add to your question how you are compiling your program with a sample program that illustrates the problem. I can only imagine that you are compiling with `-nostdlib`.

Comment: reopening, even if I know that it's a mistake. note I should have known OP was running linux by the paths in the comments...

Comment: Search all your source code. There's a good chance some piece of code is doing something very odd with `sleep`, such as defining a different function also called "sleep". it's also possible there's something wrong with the make file.

Comment: Please show your makefile and state the system. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1):

This is a linker error, not a compiler error (you can see that from the "ld returned 1 exit status" part - ld is the linker). So sleep is declared in the header, which compiles fine, but you need to ensure you include the correct library/binary file for the linking stage.

Comment: You are correct, when I made a test file for sleep it worked fine. So I'm using a makefile provided by my professor, how to ensure I've include the correct library?

Comment: @alexBrock You're probably going to need to ask your professor for help.  It's a bit hard to imagine how (or why) he's managed to disable linking against the standard library (the one that does have `sleep` in it).  You might be able to post the whole Makefile, and someone here might be able to see a good way to fix it, but if it's goofy enough to disable the standard libraries, I can easily imagine it's goofy enough to be incomprehensible.

Comment: @alexBrock update your question with the makefile and we’ll be able to tell you what’s wrong.

Comment: `sleep` is *declared* in the header, not *defined*.

Answer (score 1):

I can roughly replicate the reported behavior with the following program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}

void _start (void) {
    asm("call main;"
        "mov %eax,%ebx;"
        "movl $1,%eax;"
        "int  $0x80;");
}
```

But, it must be compiled with `-nostdlib`. From this [TIO](https://tio.run/##XU9BCoMwELznFUuqoGCK3gop/UKPPZaYpDYQo5goQvHr3Sae2s5tZ2Z3ZiXrpEQ8GCftrDScZ2d8UMfnhRDjAvTCOCiWwagSXgQivNV6LJqS79Okwzw5qDnZCEk2uPsgpvCzInxfUCms3c9xupMJtB8WyLVYq1y3659gIWuqJH7zqRNk9XqqOY0VNsS3fFjReWRXZKNWwgUjkd1iGjI3xF@saT8) example, I get:

> ```
> /tmp/ccfjKQV4.o: In function `main':
> .code.tio.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `sleep'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Which pretty closely matches the output you are reporting. To fix this, you need to provide `libc` when linking the program. This can be accomplished by adding `-lc`, as demonstrated at this [TIO](https://tio.run/##XU9BCoMwELznFUuqoGCK3gop/UKPPZaYpDYQo5goQvHr3Sae2s5tZnZ3ZiXrpEQ8GCftrDScZ2d8UMfnhRDjAvTCOCiWwagSXgQivNV6LJqS72zSYZ4c1JxshKQxuPsgpvCzInxfUCms3c9xuosJtB8WyLVYq1y3659hIWuqZH7rqRNk9XqqOY0VNsS3fFjReWRWIrsiG7USLphIbjERmRviP9a0Hw) example. But, if you are using `-nostdlib`, **this solution may not be viable** (more on that later).

---

#### `_start`

The sample program I provided is an example of how to create an x86 linux program that will call `main` and then call `exit` without needing to use the C runtime. Without the standard C runtime, linux will attempt to jump to a routine called `_start`. Since there is no C library, `exit` is called via assembly.

---

#### `-nostdlib`

The `-nostdlib` option is telling the compiler to not include the standard C runtime and C libraries when building the executable. This is sometimes used in embedded software development where the embedded platform has its own runtime. If this software is intended to run on an embedded platform, it may be erroneous to include `-lc` to the link line, since it may cause interference with embedded system's library. In that case, you may need to implement your own version of `sleep` or find a different way to pause your program.